# Set docker.image with Run response to a groovy variable

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Using

```
docker.image('mysql').inside("") {
     mysql query...
}
```

or

```
docker.image('mysql').withRun("") {
     mysql query...
}
```

How to capture the results and store to a groovy variable? Also, even piping the result to a file does not work also.

Comment: I gave up using inside and withRun and just used straight sh "docker run ....". I would have expected the docker object makes it clean to execute command and get results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sh` step to capture the cmd output as following:

```
def queryResult

docker.image('mysql').inside("") {
     queryResult = sh (script: 'mysql query', returnStdout: true).trim()

     writeFile file: 'result.txt', text: queryResult
}
```